# Zabbix web install Redhat conflicts php

Tags: rhel, yum, php, monitoring, repository

I am trying to install Zabbix on redhat 7 64bit. The zabbix server installed successfully with command `yum install zabbix-server-mysql`

But I am getting conflicts with php70u with php56u when I tried to install zabbix web console. I execute the following command : `yum install zabbix-web-mysql`

The following is the output of the command:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package zabbix-web-mysql.noarch 0:3.0.2-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: zabbix-web = 3.0.2-1.el7 for package: zabbix-web-mysql-3.0.2-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-mysql for package: zabbix-web-mysql-3.0.2-1.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56u-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.6.21-1.ius.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.21-1.ius.el7 for package: php56u-mysqlnd-5.6.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
---> Package zabbix-web.noarch 0:3.0.2-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php >= 5.4 for package: zabbix-web-3.0.2-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-gd for package: zabbix-web-3.0.2-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: zabbix-web-3.0.2-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: dejavu-sans-fonts for package: zabbix-web-3.0.2-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-bcmath for package: zabbix-web-3.0.2-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-ldap for package: zabbix-web-3.0.2-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-xml for package: zabbix-web-3.0.2-1.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 0:2.33-6.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: dejavu-fonts-common = 2.33-6.el7 for package: dejavu-sans-fonts-2.33-6.el7.noarch
---> Package mod_php70u.x86_64 0:7.0.6-1.ius.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.6-1.ius.el7 for package: mod_php70u-7.0.6-1.ius.el7.x86_64
---> Package php56u-pdo.x86_64 0:5.6.21-1.ius.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-common(x86-64) = 5.6.21-1.ius.el7 for package: php56u-pdo-5.6.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
---> Package php70u-bcmath.x86_64 0:7.0.6-1.ius.el7 will be installed
---> Package php70u-gd.x86_64 0:7.0.6-1.ius.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.4()(64bit) for package: php70u-gd-7.0.6-1.ius.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXpm.so.4()(64bit) for package: php70u-gd-7.0.6-1.ius.el7.x86_64
---> Package php70u-ldap.x86_64 0:7.0.6-1.ius.el7 will be installed
---> Package php70u-mbstring.x86_64 0:7.0.6-1.ius.el7 will be installed
---> Package php70u-xml.x86_64 0:7.0.6-1.ius.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package dejavu-fonts-common.noarch 0:2.33-6.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXpm.x86_64 0:3.5.11-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package libwebp.x86_64 0:0.3.0-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package php56u-common.x86_64 0:5.6.21-1.ius.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) for package: php56u-common-5.6.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
---> Package php70u-common.x86_64 0:7.0.6-1.ius.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56u-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.9-2.ius.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-pear for package: php56u-pecl-jsonc-1.3.9-2.ius.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-pear for package: php56u-pecl-jsonc-1.3.9-2.ius.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56u-pear.noarch 1:1.10.1-4.ius.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-xml for package: 1:php56u-pear-1.10.1-4.ius.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-posix for package: 1:php56u-pear-1.10.1-4.ius.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-cli for package: 1:php56u-pear-1.10.1-4.ius.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56u-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.21-1.ius.el7 will be installed
---> Package php56u-process.x86_64 0:5.6.21-1.ius.el7 will be installed
---> Package php56u-xml.x86_64 0:5.6.21-1.ius.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php70u-xml-7.0.6-1.ius.el7.x86_64 conflicts php-xml < 7.0
--> Processing Conflict: php70u-common-7.0.6-1.ius.el7.x86_64 conflicts php56u-common
--> Processing Conflict: php70u-common-7.0.6-1.ius.el7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php70u-xml conflicts with php56u-xml-5.6.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
Error: php70u-common conflicts with php56u-common-5.6.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Here is the repolist that I have :

```
base-local                               CELGAE Infra Management REPO - RedHat EL7 DVD                                  4,620
*epel/x86_64                             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                10,050
ius/x86_64                               IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                           302
ius-debuginfo/x86_64                     IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Debug                    55
ius-source                               IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Source                    0
optional-local                           CELGAE Infra Management REPO - RedHat EL7 OPTIONAL                             8,602
updates-local                            CELGAE Infra Management REPO - RedHat EL7 UPDATES                             10,706
zabbix/x86_64                            Zabbix Official Repository - x86_64                                               40
zabbix-non-supported/x86_64              Zabbix Official Repository non-supported - x86_64                                  4
```

I followed the documentation : https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/installation/install_from_packages

I disabled the repo ius but it does not help.

Comment: This is a side effect of the design of IUS packages. They provide their equivalent stock name so they can satisfy other packages dependencies. Unfortunately, this can confuse yum. The best work around is give yum a hand and pick your dependency manually first (php-mysql or php56u-mysqlnd).  Temporarily disabling IUS also works if you haven't yet installed related IUS packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after many hours of search and no one feedback, I was able to fix my issue. I am sharing here so it's might helps other in the future who are facing the same issue.

First, you need to install yum replace :

`yum install yum-plugin-replace`

After replace, `php-common` with your confict php version. In my case, it is `php70u-common`. Therefore, I ran the following commands :

```
yum replace php-common --replace-with php70u-common
```

Or you if it is for only php, you can do also:

```
yum replace php --replace-with php70u
```

After that, you can install the package you want. In my case, it was Zabbix.